# Error when using gzip on a file containing line breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, gzip

I'm attempting to use python's `gzip` library to streamline some python scripts that create csv output files. I've tried a number of different methods of creating the gzip file, but no matter which method I've tried, I'm running into the same issue.

My python script runs successfully, but when I try to decompress the gzip file in Finder (using MacOS 10.15.6), I'm prompted with the following error:

```
Unable to expand "file.csv.gz" into "Documents". (Error 79 - Inappropriate file type or format.)
```

After some debugging, I've narrowed down the cause of the error to the file content containing line break (`\n`) characters.

This simple example code triggers the above error on gzip expansion:

```
import gzip

content = b'Id,Food\n1,Spam\n2,Eggs\n'
f = gzip.open('file.csv.gz', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

When I remove all `\n` characters from the `content` variable, everything works fine:

```
import gzip

content = b'Id,Food,1,Spam,2,Eggs'
f = gzip.open('file.csv.gz', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

Does gzip want me to use a different line break mechanism? I'm sure I'm missing some sort of foundational knowledge about gzip or binaries, so any info that helps get me back on track would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem with Python 3.8.5, 3.7.7, 3.6.8 or 3.5.4 on Linux. `gzip -cd <file.csv.gz` succeeds for `content` with or without `\n`.

Comment: Maybe the error is with the way MacOS is handling the gzip content. I'm using Python 3.8.2. I'm also not receiving a python error. Just when I try unzipping the file in Finder

Comment: It may also happen that `gzip.py` on your Mac is buggy, and it generates broken .gz files. Can you please share the generated `file.csv.gz`, so that we can check if it's correct? You can also try to decompress it with `gzip -cd <...` on macOS or Linux.

Comment: When I run `gzip -cd <file.csv.gz` it decompresses just fine. It outputs:`Id,Food\n1,Spam\n2,Eggs\n`. Perhaps this is a MacOS error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Python's gzip. It is, arguably, a bug in macOS where it *sometimes* detects the resulting uncompressed data as an mtree by the Archive Utility, but then finds the uncompressed data violates the mtree format.

The solution is to not double-click to decompress. Use gzip to decompress.

Comment: And just to confirm, the best way to use gzip to decompress is via a terminal command correct? `gzip -d file.csv.gz`

Comment: Out of curiosity - are there any alternatives you are aware of? Would be nice if I didn't have to explain bash basics to the non-technical stakeholders on my team, but I can go there if needed

Comment: @DanielLong Correct. Or `gunzip file.csv.gz`.

Comment: @DanielLong You can use [The Unarchiver](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12). In Finder you can set that as the default to open when double-clicking, instead of Archive Utility.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for CSV is to include data with a space, eg,

```
import gzip

content = b'Id,Food\n1,Spam\n2,Green Eggs and Ham\n'
f = gzip.open('file.csv.gz', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```